# JPA search throws error "An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation"

Tags: java, sql, jpa, ejb

Issue:

I am trying to do a search by the site id to fetch the records from the AA_SITE table.

But I get the following exception while executing the invocation code. Any idea why?

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
    at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
    ... 1 more
```

**My search Invocation code :**

```
public Site ReadSite(Long siteId) {

    Query query =   em.createNamedQuery("Site.findSiteById", Site.class);
    query.setParameter("siteId",siteId);
    Site site = (Site)query.getSingleResult();    

    return site;
}
```

**Entity code:**

```
package au.sdm.aa.entity;

import au.audit.utility.model.entities.v1.VersionableEntity;  
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;   

@Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Site.findAllSitesByManagerId", 
                            query = "select o from Site o where o.managementId=:managmentId and o.parentSite IS NULL ORDER BY o.id ASC ",
                            hints={
                                @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH,value="o.colocatedSiteList"),
                                @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH_TYPE,value="EXISTS")
                            }),
                @NamedQuery(name = "Site.isThisSiteExsists", 
                            query = "select COUNT(o.id) from Site o where o.id =:siteId"),
                @NamedQuery(name = "Site.findSiteById", 
                            query = "select o from Site o where o.id =:siteId")
                })
@SequenceGenerator(name = "siteIdSequenceGen", sequenceName = "AA_SITE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@Table(name = "AA_SITE")
public class Site extends VersionableEntity {
    @SuppressWarnings("compatibility:4655825307977473383")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "siteIdSequenceGen")
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH )
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Site parentSite;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentSite", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    private List<Site> colocatedSiteList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "documentSite",  cascade = {CascadeType.ALL },orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<SiteDocument> siteDocumentList;

   @Column(name = "MANAGER_ID",nullable=false)
    private Long  managementId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contactSite", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL },orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<SiteContact> siteContactList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classSite",  cascade = {CascadeType.ALL },orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<SiteClass> siteClassList;          

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appSite", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<Application> applicationList;

    public Site() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }                        
}
```

Am not sure why this issue is happening. it would be a great help if someone could provide any valid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the `siteId` parameter  in the `ReadSite` method as `null` which in the end causes to trigger the query as:

```
select o from Site o where o.id = null
```

Having this set-up:

```
@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
```

on the entity id, you get the generated exception.

Comment: The 'siteId'  parameter in 'ReadSite' method is not null. I call the 'ReadSite' from another method and I pass the 'SiteId' as a parameter to the 'ReadSite'.   It would be a great help if you could explain if am missing something